# How to get HTTPRequest POST data?

Tags: ruby, mongrel

I'm implementing a small HTTP server with Ruby using Mongrel. My code currently looks like this:

```
require 'mongrel.rb'

class SimpleHandler < Mongrel::HttpHandler
  def process(request, response)
    puts request.body # outputs #<StringIO:0xb7656e74> 
    response.start(200) do |head,out|
      head["Content-Type"] = "application/ocsp-responder"
      out.write("hello!\n")
    end
  end
end

h = Mongrel::HttpServer.new("127.0.0.1", "5000")
h.register("/", SimpleHandler.new)
h.run.join
```

As you can see in my sample, request.body does not output the POST data. How can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[StringIO#read](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/classes/StringIO.html#M001307) should do it:

```
puts request.body.read
```

Comment: I was able to get the data using request.body.string, but your solution works as well. Thanks.